# Show that $E_f(\log f) \ge E_f (\log g)$

Tags: logarithms, convex-analysis, expected-value, jensen-inequality

> **Problem.** Let $f(x), g(x)$ be probability densities defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(x), g(x)>0$ for all $x$. Show that
> $$ E_f(\log f(x)) \ge E_f (\log g(x)) $$
> with $ E_f(h(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x) f(x) \, dx$ is the expectation of $h(x)$ with respect to the density $f(x)$.

We are allowed to use Jensen's inequality. Since $\log$ is concave, we have that

$$ \log\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) f(x) \,dx
\ge \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \log f(x) f(x) \, dx
= E_f(\log f(x)) $$

and

$$ \log\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) f(x) \, dx
\ge \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \log g(x) f(x) \, dx
= E_f(\log g(x)) $$

from [this post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Form_involving_a_probability_density_function) but I couldn't get past this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to the non-negativity of the KL divergence, see below, I hope this is helpful.

\begin{align*}
D_{KL}(p\parallel q)
&=\mathbb E_q\left[-\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right]
\\
&\geq -\log \mathbb E_q\left[\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right]
\\
&=-\log\int q(x)\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\mathrm dx
\\
&=-\log\int p(x)\mathrm dx=-\log1=0
\end{align*}

Comment: You can think of $p$ and $q$ as your $g$ and $f$, respectively.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!

Comment: @Stacker you are welcome!